# Проблема с телеграмм ботом и навигации по папке

Tags: python-3.6

столкнулся с проблемой при создании проэкта.
Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки "вперед" в телеграм боте, из папки с несколькими видео отправлялось следущее видео, а уже при нажатии кнопки "назад" отправлялось предыдущее

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Когда нажать кнопку 'вперед' можно увеличить индекс текущего видеофайла и отправить следующее видео. При нажатии кнопки 'назад можно уменьшить индекс и отправить предыдущее видео.
Реализаций есть куча
Как за основу можно взять это

```
import os
from telegram import InputMediaVideo

# получаем список видеофайлов в директории
video_files = os.listdir('/path/to/video/folder')

# сохраняем порядок видеофайлов
video_order = sorted(video_files)

# переменная для хранения индекса текущего видео
current_video_index = 0

def send_next_video(update, context):
    global current_video_index
    current_video_index = (current_video_index + 1) % len(video_order)
    video_path = os.path.join('/path/to/video/folder', video_order[current_video_index])
    update.message.reply_video(video=video_path)

def send_previous_video(update, context):
    global current_video_index
    current_video_index = (current_video_index - 1) % len(video_order)
    video_path = os.path.join('/path/to/video/folder', video_order[current_video_index])
    update.message.reply_video(video=video_path)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Если помог, отметь ответ)